# Proof that a certain combination of $I_{\nu}(z)$ Bessel functions is equal to exactly $1$

Tags: bessel-functions

Consider the function for $x>0$ and $y>0$
$$
f(x,y) := \frac{\pi x^2}{2y} \mathrm{csch}\left( \frac{\pi y}{2} \right) \left( I_{-1-i y/2}(x) I_{-1+iy/2}(x) - I_{1-i y/2}(x) I_{1+i y/2}(x)  \right) 
$$
where $I_{\nu}(z)$ is a modified Bessel function. It turns out that
$$
f(x,y) = 1
$$
which I have confirmed numerically.

How do you prove this? I have tried checking [known cross-products of Bessel functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.28) and cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the Wronskian product
$$ I_{\nu}(z) I_{-1-\nu}(z) - I_{1+\nu}(z) I_{-\nu}(z) = -\frac{2\sin \nu\pi}{\pi z} $$
and apply the [recurrence relation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.29#E1)
$$ I_{\pm \nu}(z) = \pm \frac{2\nu}{z} ( I_{-1 \pm \nu}(z) + I_{1 \pm \nu}(z) ). $$
This gives, after some cancellation,
$$ -\frac{2\sin \nu\pi}{\pi z} = \frac{z}{2\nu} ( -I_{-1+\nu}(z) I_{-1-\nu}(z) - I_{1+\nu}(z) I_{-1-\nu}(z) ) , $$
which rearranges itself into your formula.